# Questions regarding need of actions in React-Mobx

Tags: javascript, mobx, mobx-react, ecmascript-next

```js
import React from "react"
import { observable } from "mobx";
import { observer } from "mobx-react"
import { computed, action } from "mobx"

@observer
export default class Dice extends React.Component {

    @observable
    value = 1;

    @computed  
    get result() {
        return this.value > 3 ? "YOU WIN" : "YOU LOSE"
    }

    

    @action    
    handleRoll = () => {

        this.value = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1
    }

    render() {

        return (
            <div>
                <br />
                <button onClick={this.handleRoll}>Roll Dice</button> <br />
                <p>The value is {this.value}</p>
                <p>{this.result}</p>
            </div>
        )
    }

}
```

Now, i have used the action decorator for handleRoll function. I used it because my original state is changed i.e value will change everytime (most probably) as i click on roll dice button.Now even when i removed the action decoartor then still every things works fine with no errors . Now the question is if we can accomplish the task of changing the state then why to use actions at all ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default using actions is not required to change state in mobx, but it's a [good best practice in larger codebases|https://mobx.js.org/refguide/action.html#when-to-use-actions]. If you enable strict mode, mobx will throw an error if you try to modify state outside of an action.

To enable strict mode in mobx 4.0.0 and newer, use [`mobx.configure({enforceActions: true})`](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx/blob/gh-pages/docs/refguide/api.md#configure). In older versions of mobx this was accomplished with `mobx.useStrict(true)`.